# Keep order of diagonal elements when diagonalizing a matrix in Python

Tags: python, matrix, diagonal

I have a non-diagonal matrix, but with the non-diagonal elements much smaller than the diagonal ones, so upon diagonalization, I expect that the diagonal elements will change, but just a little. I am currently just using `numpy.linalg.eig` to get the eigenvalues, however I would like the order of these values to be the same as the (similar) values before diagonalization. So, if the diagonal in the original matrix was (100,200,300), after diagonalization I would like to have as output (101,202,303) and not (202,303,101). I need this in order to keep track of which value got map to which after diagonalization. How can I do this? It seems like there is no clear order to the output of `numpy.linalg.eig`? Thank you!

Comment: What is the justification that a specific eigen value has an association with a specific element on the diagonal of a matrix?

Comment: Maybe you also need eigenvectors because each eigenvalue is associated with an eigenvector.

Comment: In my case this is a physical system and indeed I do need to keep track of eigenvectors, too. Associating the eigenvectors with the eigenfunctions is easy in python, the problem is going back to the original, non-diagonal matrix. I am doing this for a physical system Hamiltonian and as an example, let's say that the original basis is based on a quantum number X (i.e. the basis are eigenvectors of X). If we have a selection rule such that I can only connect states with X varying by at most one, X=0 and X=2 won't mix.

Comment: But if upon diagonalization, the state that was initially X=2 gets some X=1 mixture, now the X=0 state can mix with it. But in order to do that, I need to keep track of the composition of the eigenvalues (i.e. what elements from the original matrix they are made of, and how much of X=2 and X=1 character they have)

Answer (score 2):

## Frame challenge

I don't think there can be a rigorous solution to this problem, surely not using straight numpy.

From an admittedly very cursory examination of the source code, I believe that to calculate the eigenvalues numpy starts by the hallowed method of calculating the roots of the determinant of the parametric matrix. **This is the fastest and most accurate method and is guaranteed to work**.

Yet, it **cannot** preserve eigenvalue order.

For simplicity, consider a two by two matrix:

[[ 10 .1 ] [.1 20]]

this has lambda-det of `L^2-30L+199.99`

But if you consider this other matrix, with the same values in the opposite order, obtained by swapping the previous diagonal...

[[ 20 .1 ] [.1 10]]

...you end up with the same determinant. So, from that one determinant, you can't tell which matrix you started from, so you can not determine the original diagonal elements' order. Proceeding with the calculations, from here onwards, that information no longer exists. You do get the eigenvalue *values*, but not their original order.

**When you build the determinant, just as if you multiplied x*y, the information about the order of the factors gets lost** (in the case of multiplication, it gets *completely* lost, always).

So the eigenvalues appear to be "shuffled" in respect to the original diagonal.

But what actually happens is not that the original values get "slightly shifted"; they are, each time, *all completely lost*, and other similar values are recreated in their place. The fact that they "look like" the previous values is a red herring. So, there's no guarantee that a match will be possible.

It's sort of the mathematical version of the "vanishing illusion" puzzles like *Teddy and the Lions*:

[image: People Vanishing illusion]

What you can *try* to do is match the values "a posteriori", i.e. select the permutation of the eigenvalues that most closely approximates the original diagonal.

There are algorithms to do that, using different metrics to determine which permutation is "closer" (usually, least squares).

A quick way would be to sort the initial diagonal values in ascending order, record the permutation used (this is O(n log n)), then sort the eigenvalues in ascending order and apply the permutation in reverse. This gets you a "close match".

However, it might still be possible to do something *akin* to what you describe using a different algorithm, e.g. Jacobi's method or other iterative method.

Note that such algorithms needs must preserve the order *locally*. The value in a place remains there. But it still might change so that you get values in an order different from the one you might expect, e.g. you start with diagonal [2.1, 1.9, 12], the first element shrinks to 1.999, the second grows to 2.001, and you might be led to believe that "the two elements got swapped".

## Implementation found around the Interwebs

As I said, my linear algebra days are long past, but I remembered that Jacobi method was iterative and so *might* fit your bill. I looked for that and stopped at the first result. It **looks** correct to me. In case it wasn't, a more focused search might still yield a working Python implementation; the theory *is* proven.

[GitHub page](https://github.com/mateuv/MetodosNumericos/blob/master/python/NumericalMethodsInEngineeringWithPython/jacobi.py)

```
a = array([[2.0,0.1,0.1],[0.1,7.0,0.1],[0.1, 0.1, 11.0]])
lam,x = jacobi(a,tol = 1.0e-9)
print(lam)

# Expected value: close to [2 7 11] in this order
[1.99693421  6.99940092 11.00366487]
```

A run of several other random values yielded consistent results.

Comment: But there are programs out there that do that (not in python, so I would need to dig quite deep to understand the details), in the form of diagonalizing hamiltonians of physical systems. In order to do that properly one needs to keep track of the initial matrix (before diagonalization), for example, not to display an energy difference that would correspond to a forbidden transition (i.e. the 2 levels/eigenvalues involve have the wrong quantum numbers). I can go into more details about such softwares, but the point is that they do exactly what I need, so it should be possible.

Comment: This is such a program: https://pgopher.chm.bris.ac.uk/index.html. If you go to the bottom of that page, what I need to do in my case is to get something similar to what they have in the bottom part of that figure i.e. peaks (in my case I don't need them to have a width) which correspond to difference between eigenvalues of a Hamiltonian. But in order to do that I need to keep track of the original matrix, as, for example, the heights of the peaks depend on what the eigenvectors contain from the original matrix.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do something *like* what you ask. It seems that there is a Jacobi implementation for Python. Try looking into that. My linear algebra days are long gone, but I believe that ought to work.

Comment: @Silviu could you add a working example and what do you expected? The order stuffs is quite confusing (a change of base - a similarity transformation - is unique up some combinatorics value). Notice further that diagonalization via polynomial method (_characteristic polynomial_) is not the only way, you could use _Gaussian elimination_ with extended matrix is possible and keeps the "order": `[M | I ] -> [I | D ]`

Comment: As @cards said, you can't do this with numpy, but you should be able to get very close with Gauss or Jacobi  or iterative diagonalization. I included the implementation I found, which *seems* to do what you asked for. But please review and test it extensively.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `numpy.linalg.eig` to compute the eigenvalues of a matrix, the eigenvalues returned are not necessarily ordered in any particular way. You can refer to the numpy manual https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html

Now to deal with this we can take an example matrix where the off-diagonal elements are non-zero but small and then try to map them to their original order

```
example_matrix = np.array([[100, 0.2, 0.3], [0.2, 200, 0.5], [0.3, 0.5, 300]])

# Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(example_matrix)

# Original diagonal elements
original_diagonal = np.diag(example_matrix)

# Sort eigenvalues by how close they are to the original diagonal elements
sorted_indices = np.argsort(np.abs(eigenvalues - original_diagonal))

# Sorted eigenvalues and eigenvectors
sorted_eigenvalues = eigenvalues[sorted_indices]
sorted_eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:, sorted_indices]

# Output the sorted eigenvalues and their corresponding eigenvectors
sorted_eigenvalues, sorted_eigenvectors
```

Result

```
(array([ 99.99915299, 199.99789408, 300.00295293]),
 array([[-0.9999969 , -0.001985  ,  0.00150496],
        [ 0.0019925 , -0.9999855 ,  0.00500279],
        [ 0.00149501,  0.00500578,  0.99998635]]))
```

Basically you need to sort the eigenvalues along with their corresponding eigenvectors based on the proximity to the original diagonal. This way you can track of the permutation that sorts the eigenvalues so you can map them back to their original order.

Comment: But this doesn't resolve my problem. The example I gave was obviously a very simple one to clarify what I meant in words. In practice I can have two numbers on the diagonal (before diagonalization) that are equal (or very close), say (100,100). After diagonalization they would become, say, (99,101). Unless I am sure that the order is preserved, I would have no way of knowing which came from where (also my matrices are quite large, so I can't do it by hand either).

Comment: I agree. You will need to have some order preservation in place to ensure which came from which element. Without that you will definitely loose track.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

# Your non-diagonal matrix
A = np.array([[10, 0.1, 0.2],[0.3, 20, 0.4], [0.5, 0.6, 30]])

# Compute eigenvalues and eigenvectors
eigenvalues, eigenvectors = np.linalg.eig(A)

# Sort eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors based on magnitudes
sorted_indices = np.argsort(np.abs(eigenvalues))
sorted_eigenvalues = eigenvalues[sorted_indices]
sorted_eigenvectors = eigenvectors[:, sorted_indices]

# Print the sorted eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors
print("Original Eigenvalues:", eigenvalues)
print("Sorted Eigenvalues:", sorted_eigenvalues)
print("Corresponding Eigenvectors:", sorted_eigenvectors)
```

Now, you can use sorted_eigenvalues and sorted_eigenvectors as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Let `diag` be the list of diagonal  elements. Sorting the list with `sorted` will allow us to find the permutation that takes `sorted_diag` to `diag`:

```
sorted_diag = sorted(diag)
perm = [sorted_diag.index(d) for d in diag]
```

`perm` will indeed be the permutation, because `[sorted_diag[i] for i in perm]` will return `diag`.

Now, because the set of eigenvalues is "similar" to the set of diagonal elements, using this permutation on the sorted array of eigenvalues should yield the eigenvalues in the order we want. If `eigens` is the array of eigenvalues, then we can do

```
sorted_eigens = sorted(eigens)
eigens_good = [sorted_eigens[i] for i in perm]
```

So the whole thing just goes:

```
mat = np.array([[203, 0.4, 0.6], [0.3, 301, 0.7], [0.6, 0.1, 101]])

diag = np.diag(mat) # [203, 301, 101]
eigens, _ = np.linalg.ein(mat) # [203.00228619, 100.99612982, 301.00158399]

sorted_diag = sorted(diag) # [101, 203, 301]
perm = [sorted_diag.index(d) for d in diag] # [1, 2, 0]

sorted_eigens = sorted(eigens) # [100.99612982, 203.00228619, 301.00158399]
eigens_good = [sorted_eigens[i] for i in perm] # [203.00228619, 100.99612982, 301.00158399]
```

And so `eigens_good` is exactly what we want, as the original order was `[203, 101, 301]`!

**note:** it may be possible to optimize this more by using something different than list comprehensions and `sorted`, but I figure this will likely be good enough.

**Same values in diagonal:**

The above won't work right away if the diagonal has identical elements, but you can get something similar to work. You just need to generate `perm` more carefully, for example, by "popping" the elements of a copy of the sorted array.

```
diag = np.diag(mat)
sorted_diag = sorted(diag)

perm = [None]  * len(diag)
temp = sorted_diag.copy()
for i, d in enumerate(diag):
    index_d = temp.index(d)
    perm[i] = index_d
    temp[index_d] = None
```

With `diag = [203, 101, 404, 101]`, `[sorted_diag[i] for i in perm]` correctly results in `diag` again, so it should be fine to use `perm` in the same as way before with `eigens`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the main issue, related to the case when the diagonal elements are equal

Comment: Does the edit solve that case? It might not find the "perfect" relationship between eigenvalues and diagonal elements, but I suspect that's technically impossible to do. But at least the diagonal elements will be matched to eigenvalues close to them.